# Set environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I want to create an application that takes the audio file and understands the intention of the speaker. I am using Dialogflow https://dialogflow.com/ to accomplish the task.

I tried this java code in Eclipse and I was able to get the intention of the speaker.

```
public static QueryResult detectIntentAudio(
          String projectId,
          byte[] audioData,
          String sessionId,
          String languageCode)
          throws Exception {
        // Instantiates a client
        try (SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create()) {
          // Set the session name using the sessionId (UUID) and projectID (my-project-id)
          SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);
          System.out.println("Session Path: " + session.toString());

          // Note: hard coding audioEncoding and sampleRateHertz for simplicity.
          // Audio encoding of the audio content sent in the query request.
          AudioEncoding audioEncoding = AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16;
          int sampleRateHertz = 44100;

          // Instructs the speech recognizer how to process the audio content.
          InputAudioConfig inputAudioConfig = InputAudioConfig.newBuilder()
              .setAudioEncoding(audioEncoding) // audioEncoding = AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16
              .setLanguageCode(languageCode) // languageCode = "en-US"
              .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRateHertz) // sampleRateHertz = 16000
              .build();

          // Build the query with the InputAudioConfig
          QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setAudioConfig(inputAudioConfig).build();

          // Read the bytes from the audio file
          byte[] inputAudio = audioData;



          //System.out.println("Path is:"+Paths.get(audioFilePath));
          // Build the DetectIntentRequest
          DetectIntentRequest request = DetectIntentRequest.newBuilder()
              .setSession(session.toString())
              .setQueryInput(queryInput)
              .setInputAudio(ByteString.copyFrom(inputAudio))
              .build();

          // Performs the detect intent request
          DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(request);

          // Display the query result
          QueryResult queryResult = response.getQueryResult();
          System.out.println("====================");
          System.out.format("Query Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getQueryText());
          System.out.format("Detected Intent: %s (confidence: %f)\n",
              queryResult.getIntent().getDisplayName(), queryResult.getIntentDetectionConfidence());
          System.out.format("Fulfillment Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getFulfillmentText());

          return queryResult;
        }
}
```

And I set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the Run Configuration in Eclipse.

However, when I try to run the same code in Android Studio, I get the following error.

```
 The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
```

I have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable set in my ~/.bashrc.
I tried putting the variable in studio.vmoptions.
I could not solve the issue. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: i think you may need to restart your machine after updating your bashrc (?)

Comment: I did that couple of times. It did not work.